# What's the difference between FSO.DeleteFolder() method and oWS.Run "%comspec% /c rmdir ...", 1, True?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I got a vbs that I wrote.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set oWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
Set objFolderUsers = FSO.GetFolder("\\"& strComputer &"\C$\Users\").Subfolders  
...
```

Later, I do something like :

```
For Each objFlder In objFolderUsers

    user = Right(objFlder, Len(objFlder) - InStrRev(objFlder, "\"))
    temp = objFlder & "\AppData\Local\Temp\"

    'That's the line !...       
    If FSO.FolderExists(temp) Then FSO.DeleteFolder(temp)

    If Not IsExcludeProfile(user) Then
        If Left(objFlder.DateLastModified, 4) <= minYear Then 
            oWS.Run "%comspec% /c rmdir " & objFlder & " /s /q", 0, True
            oWS.Run "%comspec% /c net user " & user & " /delete", 0, True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

my question is : Is there a difference between **FSO.DeleteFolder(temp)** and **oWS.Run "%comspec% /c rmdir " & temp, 1, True** because when I do the first all things are OK but when I do the second (the oWS.Run) AND objFlder = "Default" it is all deleted, not just the Temp as I want ...

Comment: looks like you're passing `objFlder` to oWS.Run, instead of the full path to the folder, which is `temp`

Comment: I used to pass temp .....  
**"%comspec% /c rmdir " & temp, 1, True**

Comment: Why use `oWS.Run` to do soemthing as simple as delete a folder? You are already using the `FileSystemObject` to iterate through the `Folder` objects so why not use [`objFlder.Delete(True)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k4wket3(v=vs.84).aspx)?

Comment: i'll give it a try !... 

Comment: It works !! thnx Lankymart !...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put enclosing quotes in the file name passed to the rmdir, because blank spaces may terminate the string that it receives before its end:

```
oWS.Run "%comspec% /c rmdir """ & objFlder & """ /s /q", 0, True
```

Just reminding that "" inside a string literal in vbs means a single " in the contents of the string.

Comment: The fact is that oWS.Run command works for all others directory i don't want to delete (_Administrator_, _Public_, _etc._) ?...

Comment: @Louis-Alex It will work for folder without spaces the minute you get a folder like `My Documents` *(for example)* it will not work without being enclosed in double quotes *(`"My Documents"`)*.